# LEAD and LAG window fucntions in Django orm, how to apply on single object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Question is regarding `Window` functions usage in Django.

I have a following model:

```
class EntriesChangeLog(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type',
        'object_id',
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        verbose_name='user',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='access_logs',
    )
    access_time = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='access_time',
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
    as_who = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Status of the accessed user.',
        choices=UserStatusChoices.choices,
        max_length=7,
    )
    operation_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Type of the access operation.',
        choices=OperationTypeChoices.choices,
        max_length=6,
    )
    state = JSONField(
        verbose_name='Model state before save or delete.',
        encoder=CustomEncoder,
    )
```

My goal here is to annotate each object in queryset of this model with `state` field from previous and next object in queryset with same `object_id` and `content_type_id`. This is needed to get this annotation later in detail view and calculate difference between previous, current and future state.

My queryset in get_object:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    model = self.kwargs['model_name']
    instance_pk = self.kwargs['instance_pk']

    self.queryset = self.model.objects.filter(
        object_id=instance_pk,
        content_type__model=model.__name__.lower(),
        content_type__app_label=model._meta.app_label.lower(),
    ).select_related('user', )

    return super().get_queryset()


def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    q = queryset.annotate(
        next_val=Window(
            expression=Lead('state'),
            order_by=F('id').asc()
        ),
        prev_val=Window(
                expression=Lag('state'),
                order_by=F('id').asc(),
        ),
    )
    obj = q.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).first()

    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

    return obj
```

analogue in RAWSQL

```
SELECT
       id,
       state,
       LEAD("state") OVER(ORDER BY "id" ) AS "next_val",
       LAG("state") OVER(ORDER BY "id") AS "prev_val"
        
FROM "administration_entrieschangelog"
where object_id =158 and content_type_id=7
```

It works fine when there are more then one object in queryset, that is in ListView. But in detail view it seems like `WHERE` works before `SELECT` and both annotations return `NULL`. It seems like that `WINDOW` function in  queryset with only one single object in it restricted only by this object and `LEAD` and `LAG` cant see outside it’s neighbors.

Question is – is it possible to have these 2 annotations for single object somehow?

Comment: What's the issue in above code ?